# Ping list of DNS address and return IP address in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, dns, ping

Giving a list of DNS stored in .csv workbook, how to iterate over the list of those DNS ping them then print a list of IP addresses? The following code does not work properly.

```
import csv


with open('masterlist.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
your_list = list(reader)
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + your_list)
print(your_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the contents of file `masterlist.csv` looks like this:

```
google.com
stackoverflow.com
```

This works on Windows. Subprocess library is a superset of os.system and you should use it instead.

```
from subprocess import check_output

def get_ip(domain):
    # quick and dirty way of retrieving the ip address, 
    # better use regular expression
    response = check_output(['ping', '-n', '1', domain]).split()[2]
    return response.decode('utf8')

with open('masterlist.csv', 'r') as f:
    ip_addresses = {domain: get_ip(domain) for domain in f.read().splitlines()}

print(ip_addresses)
```